# Understanding GCP Composer autoscaling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a Composer environment that uses composer-2.0.17-airflow-2.2.5 image.
There are a few small and fast DAGS and one large main DAG that runs 6 times a day and lasts approx 10 minutes. In this main DAG there are total of 120 tasks with such dependencies that there are times when there could be about 25 concurring tasks running at the same time.
[image: 1]

***Resources configs:***
[image]

***Airflow configs overrides:***

[image]

Every time this Dag runs I expect to see the workers scale up, but from monitoring section i see only 1 active worker and the CPU and memory near the limit.
Ideally i want it to scale up when this dag runs and scale down during the rest of the day.
But when i use less powerful configs, the the tasks don't even start. I tried to play with different Airflow overrides, but did not achieve much.

Also, according to composer documentation,  "Airflow workers run as Deployments in your environment's cluster". In my case, I have Worker as a Pod type. Maybe that is why it doesn't scale? As I understand, to be scalable, it has to be Deployments type.

[image]

How should i configure the cluster to use the advantage of autoscaling?
I am already thinking to switch to Composer 1 :(
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Daria, I have the same issue, it looks like my workers are not autoscaling. I'll keep you updated in case I find a solution... I was wondering if trying to change the .cfg file, it worked years ago on an on-premise configuration

Comment: @FedericoSala, thank you so much! Yes, pls let me know if you find the solution

Comment: I found some useful hints in this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/optimize-environments look at the "Monitor worker pod evictions" paragraph

Comment: @FedericoSala yes i checked that doc as well and decreased worker_concurrency, but still see 1 active worker even though tasks pile up in the queue. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Composer 2 environments automatically scale in response to the demands of your executed DAGs and tasks:

- If your environment experiences a heavy load, Cloud Composer automatically increases the number of workers in your environment.
- If your environment does not use some of its workers, these workers are removed to save environment resources and costs.
- You can set the minimum and maximum number of workers for your environment. Cloud Composer automatically scales your environment within the set limits. You can adjust these limits at any time.

The number of workers is adjusted based on the Scaling Factor Target metric. This metric is calculated based on:

- Current number of workers
- Number of tasks in a queue that are not assigned to a worker
- Number of idle workers
- celery.worker_concurrency Airflow configuration option

Comment: Eduardo, thank you for your reply. Yes, I have read all that in the composer docs. Like I said, it does not scale during the heavy load, like its supposed to. I constantly see 1 worker even though tasks pile up in the queue

Comment: Hello @Daria - did you ever get this worked out?

Comment: @PatrickSteil I think i played with those setting further, decreased concurrency, increased max_active_tasks_per_dag ect, and it started to scale. Although Im pretty sure I tried that in the beginnig, but it did not work for some reason