# How to Resolve Workers Not Scaling with 100s of Queued Tasks in Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: airflow, celery, dbt, google-cloud-composer

Context:

- Using Google Cloud Composer to schedule and orchestrate some tasks.
- There are around 20 active DAGs currently. It will grow over time (around 40-50).
- Each DAG has 4 tasks. They are scheduled to run every hour.
- Each task is a dbt run command. Every task selects specific set of models.
- Each task typically take around 1-5 mins depending on the selected models. They are not very resource intensive. Total DAG run shouldnt take more than 10-15 mins.

**My problem is that the workers not scaling even though there are 100s of tasks queued in celery.**

As you can see below, tasks keep getting queued but the worker is not increasing.
[image: Airflow tasks & workers]

This is my resource configuration:
[image: Resource]

And this is my only Airflow configuration that I have overriden:
[image: Airflow configuration]

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the active worker 0 even though minimum is 1? I know I dont need more resource per worker to execute the task because the tasks used to get executed before.

---

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125720/understanding-gcp-composer-autoscaling) already. It suggested to reduce the `worker_concurrency` (which is already small in my case) and increase the `max_active_tasks_per_dag` (this setting is useless because tasks need to run sequentially in my DAGs)

According to [the documentation](https://arc.net/l/quote/elsojrkx), it uses `Scale Factor Target` metric to scale the workers. I've checked the metric, and it keeps on increasing but the workers dont scale. It stays at 0 for some reason!
[image: Scale Factor Target]